RDP to Ubuntu works from Windows, not from Guacamole
I'm using Apache Guacamole to connect easyly to different kind of VM.
I can connect to my Debian VM through Guacamole with SSH conf, I can connect to my Windows VM through Guacamole with RDP conf but when I try to configure Guacamole to connect to my Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop VM using RDP : this doesn't work :(
The connection seems to be established because I don't have the error message wich says that it can't reach the host, but I get immediatly a message "you've been disconnected".
For Guacamole conf, always selecting RDP as Protocol, IP address as Host, 3389 as Port, I tried different Security Mode (Nothing, NLA, Auto...) and with or without ignoring server certificate : no change.
Nevertheless I don't have any issue to connect to this Ubuntu VM using my RDP Windows client, wich drives me crasy because I don't understand what Guacamole needs more to be able to connect...
Any idea ?
